# How to do an onclick ajax call to a php file, with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, onclick

I have a link, which links to domain.com , when a person clicks, I want it to do an ajax call to counter.php and post 2 variables to it, so it can add 1 to the views for that link.

I have a link:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com" onClick="addHit('12345', '1')" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Link Title</a>
```

How would I do this with jquery?

EDIT:

I tried something like this

```
function addHit(str, partNumber){
$.get("counter.php", { version: str, part: partNumber })                
}
```

It seems to work, but in firebug, the request never completes... it just does that "working..." animation. counter.php echos out some text when its done (doesnt need to show up anywhere).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
function addHit(data1, data2)
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://domain.com/counter.php",
       data: "var1=data1&var2=data2",
       success: function(msg){
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); //Anything you want
       }
     });
}
```

Comment: Im looking at this thru firebug, and it never "completes" the requests, it just has a working.... animation, as if its hanging.

Comment: Try accessing your PHP directly and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a callback on success

```
function addHit(str, partNumber){
$.get(
"counter.php", 
{ 
 version: str, 
 part: partNumber 
},
function(data){
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
 })
)};
```

Comment: There is a success callback, and it works. Yet its still doing the spinning dance.

Comment: Hmmm, I've tried it in my machine and the code & Firebug works. I can't seem to reproduce your timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of an anchor, you're leaving the page, so firebug's going to show some weird behavior here as it thinks execution would stop.  Unless you're also preventing the default event behavior of the anchor...you're leaving the page and the request (in firebug's view) is discarded.