# Get value from array of textbox with array of buttons

Tags: php

it's the 2nd time i post here. Again i'm not too proficient in logic nor PHP, so please bear with my messy codes :)

I have an array of textboxes with value and there are array of buttons next to it. 
i've managed to display the value of the text box with the corresponding button into a dialog box (thanks to Mr.Barmer from here)

Then i intend to save the specific value from the textbox that i have captured into the database, here i have no clue what i should do. I try to "echo" the value of the textbox by insert it into

```
($link=((document.getElementById('link$i').value)))
```

but i got no result.

My question is: what should i add to my codes to retrieve the value from the textbox, when i clicked the corresponding button and save it to database, or simply capture the value and store it in

```
(ex:$link=$_POST['link'])
```

then post it using `echo $link`?

here's the piece of my PHP codes i'm talking about:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * from tempimg"); 
while($hasil = mysql_fetch_array($data)){     
    $i++;
    echo "<tr>
        <td align='center'><input type= checkbox name=check[] 
                value=$hasil[idFoto]</td>
        <td align='center'><img src=$hasil[thumbPath]></td>
        <td align='center'>$hasil[imgName]</td>
        <td align='center'>$hasil[thumbPath]</td>
        <td align='center'>$hasil[Path]</td>
        <td align='center'>

        <label class=text_label> $hasil[imgLink]</label>
        <div class=edit></div>
        <input type=text align=center value=$hasil[imgLink] 
                name=link[{$hasil['idFoto']}] id=link$i />
        <div class=clear></div> 

        <td align=center>

        <button type=submit =
            onClick=\"return confirm('you clicked button $i 
                with ID: $hasil[idFoto] '+'value: '
                +(document.getElementById('link$i').value))\">
        <img src=images/sav.png alt=search-btn id=img />
        </button>

        </td>
        <td align=center><img src=images/del.png></img></td>";    
}
```

and here's the SS of the page that i'm working now
http://imgur.com/FtKAs8K

just need to get the "70" and the "test.com" value and "echo" it, the rest of database query i'll try to work out myself.
So i humbly request help from the people here, please help me. Thank you for your attention

Comment: You are attempting to display values retrieved via Javascript in a PHP script. This is going to require either some AJAX or submitting the values to an additional PHP page via a URL query.
Take a look at this page: http://www.coderslexicon.com/the-basics-of-passing-values-from-javascript-to-php-and-back/

Comment: @DevlshOne Um Mr.DevlshOne,is that means i can't directly "echo" it on my page? or is there any other method then using ajax or submit the value to another php page?
i appreciate your quick reply :)

Comment: I took the database part out of the title, because it appears to be a separate issue and not really part of this post.

Comment: @Smandoli ah yeah, okay, no problem :)

Comment: That's correct. You cannot "directly" `echo` a Javascript value in a PHP script. Using AJAX, you could write it to an existing element. Or you would need to treat it as a form variable and `POST` or `GET` it on another page.

Comment: I second DevlshOne's comment. You might want to use jQuery and then tie the checkboxes to onClick event with should send checkbox value to your backend PHP page using AJAX.

Comment: @DevlshOne Mr.DevlshOne can you show me a bit how to get the value on the second page or is it possible to the get value on the origin page? because this code is in the <form method=post>"piece of code above"</>

Comment: I'll help you out some... give me a few minutes to put something together.

Comment: @Maximus2012 sadly, the check boxes at the image intended to make whether the images appear or not at the index page. 
but thank you for your answer, i really appreciate it, and i'll be glad if you have another way to solve this problem :)

Comment: @DevlshOne thank you Mr.DevlshOne, i'll wait for it, thank you very much, i left clueless what should i do with it, thank you very much :)

Comment: My bad here. I mistook the textboxes for the checkboxes. But the same solution that I mentioned above applies here. In this case, you can tie the save button to a jQuery onClick() event which will send the values of the textbox to the php page using an AJAX POST request when the save button is clicked. Once you have the data on the backend PHP page, you can further process it. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496579/how-to-do-an-onclick-ajax-call-to-a-php-file-with-jquery you are looking at somewhat similar solution here.

Comment: @Maximus2012 i am sorry i didn't make my post clearly, after i looked at the link that you gave me, i understand nothing (my apology). Forgive me, i'm a total noob at this area of expertise :(

Comment: look at DevlshOne's answer below. That is what I was trying to say. Just make sure that you have jQuery linked to your code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll need to change your PHP code (above) to look like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.saveButton',function() {
        var imageNumber = $(this).closest('tr').data('imgNum');
        var imageLink = $(this).closest('tr').data('imgLink');
        $.get('process_img.php',{n:imgNumber,l:imgLink});
    });
});
</script>    
<?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * from tempimg"); 
while($hasil = mysql_fetch_array($data)){     
    $i++;
?>
<tr data-imgNum="<?=$i;?>" data-imgLink="<?=$hasil['imgLink'];?>">
    <td align='center'><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?=$hasil['idFoto'];?>" /></td>
    <td align='center'><img src="<?=$hasil['thumbPath'];?>" /></td>
    <td align='center'><?=$hasil['imgName'];?></td>
    <td align='center'><?=$hasil['thumbPath'];?></td>
    <td align='center'><?=$hasil['Path'];?></td>
    <td align='center'>
        <label class="text_label"><?=$hasil['imgLink'];?></label>
        <div class="edit"></div>
        <input type="text" align="center" value="<?=$hasil['imgLink'];?>" name="link[{<?=$hasil['idFoto'];?>}" id="link<?=$i;?>" />
        <div class="clear"></div> 
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="button" class="saveButton">
            <img src="images/sav.png" alt="search-btn" id="img" />
        </input>
    </td>
    <td align="center"><img src="images/del.png" /></td>
<?php
}
?>
```

Then you'll need to write a new PHP script named `process_img.php`:

```
<?php
$n = $_REQUEST['n']; // this is the NUMBER (70)
$i = $_REQUEST['i']; // this is the LINK (test.com)
//  save this info to the database
?>
```

This gives you a terrific head start. Look for tutorials online.......